# json.Dumps - C# equivalent?

Tags: c#, python, json

I have the following API - documentation which seems to be written in Python:

```
request = {
"username": "johndoe47",
"password": "secret12345"
}
apiConnection.request("POST", "/api/session?sid=" + sid, json.dumps(request))
response = json.loads(apiConnection.getresponse().read())
```

I need to access this REST-Service via C#

I am a bit unsure, what "json.dumps" does. I tried the following:

```
data="{\"Username\":\"johndoe47\",\"password\":\"secret12345\"}";

    HttpWebRequest request=HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/api/session?sid=workingsid");
            request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        request.BeginGetResponse((x) =>
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(x))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                retval = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }, null);
```

I expect whatever json.dumps() does is not the same as I have done with "data=" as the server response is "missing username"

Comment: What is apiConnection for type of object? json.dumps(x) just serializes the object.

Comment: But shouldn't the serialized object look exactlly like my "data"?

Comment: Yes, that should be the same,
request = {'one': '1', 'two' : '2'}

print(json.dumps(request))

prints {"one": "1", "two": "2" }, that's why I'm wondering what type of request you're sending, since this might be glued in the header instead of in the content like you're sending.

Comment: it was in fact a typo (Username was with a big "U" instead of a small "u")

Answer (score 0):

In python json.dump(s)(..) serializes a given Python data structure to JSON. The API provides two different calls, the first is the plane json.dump(..). This one writes the output of the serialization process to a file like object. The other one, json.dumps(..) returns the serialized data structure as a string. So in your example above, the content of the request is a string representing of a JSON serialized Python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the **json.dumps** command in C# language is **JsonConvert.SerializeObject**
It is better to use a class type for the argammon method.

```
var body = new SampleClass() {username = "johndoe47",password = "secret12345"};

var restClient = new RestClient("/api/session?sid=" + sid);
var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
  restRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  restRequest.AddJsonBody(body);

var restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClassResult>(restResponse.Content);
```